# HTML If I add some character to the text so it moves the next text

Tags: html

I have problem with texts in HTML
This is my code:

```
<table width="100%"> 
    <tr> 
        <td align="left"><p style="font-family:arial;font-size:13px;color:white;">10000</p></td>
        <td align="center"><p style="font-family:arial;font-size:13px;color:white;">100 </p></td>
        <td align="right"><p style="font-family:arial;font-size:13px;color:white;">100 </p></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want it, when I add any character to first TD (align left) it move second and third TD (align center and align right)

Thank for every answer Have nice day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the width so they don't resize to fit whatever content is in the cells, e.g.

```
 <table>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="70%">January</td>
    <td width="30%">$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_width.asp

Answer (score 0):

align=left/center/right just aligns the content of the cell.
the second and third cells move because the first becomes larger.
if you want fixed table, use width for the cells, so they dont change size.